# Каким образом сделать если при синхронном чтение с помощью fs файла нету, то значению "one" присвайлась "none"?

Tags: javascript

Я начинающий в `javascript` и создаю бота в дискорде. Я хотел бы если при прочтение файла его не оказалось — он бы присвайвал `one = "none"`. 
Мой не удачный код:

```js
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const fs = require('fs');

    const one = fs.readFileSync(`./one.txt`, {"encoding": "utf-8"});
    if(!one) return one = "none";
```

Но бот будто не видит строчку `if(!one) return one = "none";` и просто выдаёт ошибку что нет файла

Comment: что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: `else { return one='none'}`, не?

Comment: Grundy, он будто не видит строчку "if(!one) return one = "1";", он просто говорит что нет файла.

Comment: doox911, я не до конца понял ваш вариант решение

Comment: @ДенисВоронин а что выведется в консоль если распечатать значение переменной `one`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, в консоль выдаёт (node:9396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './playerData/one.txt', если файла нет.

Comment: сделайте `var one; try{one = fs.readFileSync...} catch(e){one="none"}`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, оо, спасибо вам большое, я на поиск решение этой проблемы потратил более неделе, спасибо !

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а в чём разница ?

Comment: @ДенисВоронин Вы не поняли суть `stackoverflow`, ответ может помочь другим участникам, которые придут из поисковиков в будущем, а комментарии никто не читает,

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, тогда стоит всё же написать в ответ

Comment: @ДенисВоронин ну, я уже =), Это прекрасно что я сейчас трачу время на помощь лично Вам, но будет еще лучше если это поможет еще кому-то =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде строчка:

```
const one = fs.readFileSync(`./one.txt`, {"encoding": "utf-8"});
```

выбрасывает исключение, по этому код за ней далее не выполняется.

Используйте конструкцию `try{...}catch(e){...}` чтобы его отловить:

```
let one;
try {  
    one = fs.readFileSync(`./one.txt`, {"encoding": "utf-8"});
} catch(e) { 
    one = "none"; // Если было выброшено исключение
}
```